# dimension of ideal of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, commutative-algebra

I would like to determine the dimension as $\mathbb C$-vector space of the set of polynomials of degree $n$ that lie in $(x_0x_1-x_2^2)=I$ where $I$ is the principal ideal of$\{x_0x_1-x_2^2\}$ in $ \mathbb C[x_0,x_1,x_2]$. My idea is that $I$ should be similar to the set of polynomials of dimension $n-2$. Any suggestion to compute this dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is exactly right: for every polynomial $p \in I$, we can write $p = (x_0 x_1 - x_2^2) \cdot q$ for some polynomial $q$.  If $\deg(p)\leq n$, then we must have $\deg(q) = n-2$.  The question now becomes, what is the dimension of the vector space of polynomials in $3$ variables with degree less than or equal to $n-2$?

A nice basis for this space is the monomials with degree at most $n -2$, so we just need to count the number of monomials $x_0^a x_1^b x_2^c$ with $a + b + c \leq n-2$.  Defining $d: = n - 2 - a - b - c$, we get that the quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$ is a weak composition of $n - 2$, i.e. some parts may be zero.  [The number of these is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)): there are $$\binom{n-2 +4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{n+1}{3}$$
many of them, implying that this is the dimension.

Comment: Sorry but I asked for the case when the degree of $p$ is exactly $n$. So the degree of $q$ should be exactly $n-2$ and so we are looking for the dimension of the vector space of polynomials in 3 variables with degree equal to $n-2$. Right?

Comment: So actually the question was easier and I found the dimension. By the way your help was fundamental for me to construct (and to convince myself) of the bijection with the space of polynomials of degree $n-2$. Thank you